# Combining and extracting attributes from 2 columns to populate a third (Concatenate)

Tags: python, field-calculator, attribute-table, combine

I am working with a FEMA flood zone shapefile which contains a FIELD_ZONE field and a SUBTY field.  I created a third field called ZONE_TYPE that needs to be populated by combining or extracting elements of the other two. So if FLD_ZONE = A, Ae, D, V, etc, then ZONE_TYPE needs to be 1 PCT;  if the FIELD_ZONE = X and SUBTY = Annual .2, then ZONE_TYPE needs to be .2 PCT.  I'm guessing I use the field calculator, but I am not a code person (it's like a foreign language to me), and have no idea how to build the block.

Comment: If those are the only two conditions you have, you could do this very easily with no coding, just use Select by Attribute and a short SQL query.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Both QGIS and ArcGIS for Desktop have a field calculator.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary in the code block, that way it's easy to update or add options if necessary.  Before running the calculation, be sure to save the expression so you can reuse it.

Code Block:

```
def translate(input_value):
  out_value = None
  dict = {
      ["A", "Ae", "D", "V"]:"1 PCT",
      ["X"]:".2 PCT"
    }
  for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    if input_value in key:
      out_value = value

  return out_value
```

Expression:

```
translate(!FLD_ZONE!)
```

If you run that calculation on the ZONE_TYPE field it should do what you need.  A dictionary is a set of keys and values, and it surrounded by {}.  In this case, the keys are lists of values that should be translated into the corresponding value.  If no match is found, the value returned will be `null`. Hope it helps!